# Mybatis generator configuration set tableName case sensitive

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

This is my xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN" "mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">
<generatorConfiguration>
    <context id="DB2SAMPLE" defaultModelType="flat" targetRuntime="MyBatis3">

        <plugin type="org.mybatis.generator.plugins.RenameExampleClassPlugin">
            <property name="searchString" value="Example$"/>
            <property name="replaceString" value="Criteria"/>
        </plugin>

        <plugin type="org.mybatis.generator.plugins.CaseInsensitiveLikePlugin" />

        <plugin type="org.mybatis.generator.plugins.RowBoundsPlugin" />

        <commentGenerator>
            <property name="suppressAllComments" value="true" />             
        </commentGenerator>

        <jdbcConnection driverClass="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" connectionURL="jdbc:db2://LOCALHOST:50000/mydb" userId="username" password="password">
        </jdbcConnection>

        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="foo.package" targetProject="src/main/java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
            <property name="trimStrings" value="false" />
        </javaModelGenerator>

        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="foo.package" targetProject="src/main/resources">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
        </sqlMapGenerator>

        <javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER" targetPackage="foo.package" targetProject="src/main/java">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
        </javaClientGenerator>

        <table schema="SCHEMA" tableName="MyTable" alias="MYTABLE" domainObjectName="MYTABLE"/>

    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

The problem is that it not found the table `MyTable` because it search `MYTABLE`.

How can I setup MyBatis generator for searching case sensitive name `MyTable`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.codeday.top/2016/12/22/6853.html

```
1， If schema，catalog or tablename There are spaces in ， So what format is set ， On the exact use of the specified format to query ；
2， otherwise ， If the database identifier uses uppercase ， that MBG Automatically turn table name into uppercase search ；
3， otherwise ， If the database identifier uses lowercase ， that MBG Automatically turn table name to lowercase search ；
4， otherwise ， Query using the specified case format ；
 Additional ， If the table is created ， Using "" Specify database object size ， Even if the database identifier is used ， In this case a table name is created using a given case size ；
 At this time ， Please set delimitIdentifiers="true" Case preserving format ；
```